Is it permissible to be a fashion designer?
Asalamu alaikum. Is it haram to engage in fashion design if you are careful not to cross the line to haram? I wish to study fashion and provide opportunities for stylish, pretty and accessible clothing for women and girls of all ages. However, I do not know if it would be haram to be - and engage - in the industry itself.
